# Can execute JS function in the browser at KarateDriver?

Tags: karate

When using KarateDriver, I want to define and execute JS function in the browser.
Is is possible?

I want to define it like:

```
* def someFn =
"""
function(param) {
  // DOM operation in the browser
  // Event handling in the browser
  return
}
"""

* assert someFn('param1') == '<span>param1</span>'
```

---

Edit1:

I define and execute;

```
* def keyword = 'karate'
* def formSubmit =
  """
  function(formId) {
      var formElem = document.getElementById(formId);
      formElem.submit();
  }
  """

Given driver 'https://github.com/search'
    And driver.input('input[name=q]', keyword)
When driver.eval(formSubmit('search_form'))
Then eval driver.waitUntil(driver.location == 'https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=' + keyword + '&ref=simplesearch')
```

but this feature is failure.

```
javascript evaluation failed: driver.eval(formSubmit('search_form')), ReferenceError: "document" is not defined in <eval> at line number 2
```

Can it use DOM operations?

---

Edit2:

I can define and execute the JS function:

```
* def getSubmitFn =
    """
    function(formId) {
        return "var formElem = document.getElementById('" + formId + "');"
             + "formElem.submit();"
    }
    """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `driver.eval()` where the argument is raw javascript code as a string. I think this is sufficient for your needs:

```
* match driver.eval("location.href") == webUrlBase + '/page-01'
* assert driver.eval('1 + 2') == 3
```

EDIT: the JS engine for Karate and the Browser JS engine is different and there is no connection. So you have to pass JS as raw strings to `driver.eval()` here is an example that works for submitting a form.

```
* def getSubmitFn = 
"""
function(formId) {
  return "document.getElementById('" + formId + "').submit()" 
}
"""
* def temp = getSubmitFn('eg02FormId')
* print temp
* driver.eval(temp)
```

EDIT: I just remembered, `* driver.eval()` is valid, no need to do `* eval karate.eval()`

Typically what you pass to `driver.eval()` can be simple, but it has to be a string, and you cannot use Karate variables (you have to hard-code them when creating the JS dynamically). You can use DOM objects and functions. You can have multiple statements of JS separated by `;`.

Comment: I modified the question contents.
I want to use DOM operations, but JS functions is failure.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I can execute JS function in browser.
But it must write JS function on one line, so are there any techniques to write it in multiple lines?

Comment: @takanorig I just edited. `getSubmitFn` is a normal Karate JS function, you can use multiple lines. it can return any string (even multiple lines of JS) which has to be valid DOM JS. so `temp` here is just a string

Comment: I can do it like as Edit2.
If I want to the multiple lines of JS, do I have to use ```+``` for string concatenation?

Comment: @takanorig yes. note that you can do `* text = ` instead of `* def = ` for multi-line strings: https://github.com/intuit/karate#text - and then use the `replace` keyword: https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace - as an alternative approach

Comment: OK, I did well with ```text``` and ```replace``` !

Comment: @takanorig great :)