# Unable to execute JS from karate feature file

Tags: javascript, karate

I am trying to execute a JavaScript from karate feature file for implementing a dynamic wait of web element on browsers

As described in documentation, I am using script method to execute the script below script.

```
 * def waitForElementToDisplay =
 """
 function (selector, checkFrequencyInMs, timeoutInMs) {
 var startTimeInMs = Date.now();
 (function loopSearch() {
 if (document.evaluate(selector, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, 
 null).singleNodeValue != null) {
 return ;
}
else {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (timeoutInMs && Date.now() - startTimeInMs > timeoutInMs)
      return;
    loopSearch();
  }, checkFrequencyInMs);
}
})();
}
"""
```

I have tried directly calling this js using script method, `* script(waitForElementToDisplay("//*[text()='Show card number']",1000,10000))` inside my feature file but I am getting below error

```
109 * script(waitForElementToDisplay("//*[text()='Show card number']",1000,10000))
14:33:22.972 src/test/java/tests/android/imageText.feature:109
* script(waitForElementToDisplay("//*[text()='Show card number']",1000,10000))
js failed:
>>>>
01: script(waitForElementToDisplay("//*[text()='Show card number']",1000,10000))
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined
- <js>.loopSearch(Unnamed:4)

src/test/java/tests/android/imageText.feature:109
```

Comment: I don't have an answer to this question and my opinion is you are doing something un-necessary. maybe you are used to other frameworks and think that karate also needs you to write some wait helpers. NO. please read the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#wait-api

Comment: @PeterThomas : I have tried all the waits to dynamically wait for element described in karate documentation , but still the test s were getting failed. Since karate allow to use java script within feature file, i was expecting we can write our own custom wait. I also check the steps you have suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196523/can-execute-js-function-in-the-browser-at-karatedriver

Comment: Also I am still getting the same error If I am calling function like    * def getElementByXpath =

    """
    function (path) {
  return "document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue";
}
    """

Comment: sorry I can't help any more, I'm sure you understand how tough UI automation can be and it completely depends on how complex your UI is and how much JS is involved. you are welcome to contribute improvements to Karate if needed